# Insert data and generate grid dynamically in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need some ideas for to do the follow:

I need to build a table dynamically and insert and update the data in the db with codeigniter.

```
$dates=array (date1, date2, ......daten) (cols)
$people=array(name1, name2, ......namen) (rows)

             date1   date2   date3 
name1          3      5        8
name2          2      6        9
name3          5      5        1
name4          10     2        8
```

In the db I need to register:

```
name1, date1 and 3
name1, date2 and 5
name2, date1 and 2
....
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution has worked well for me, you just need to collate your array carefully.
(Taken from the PHP Cookbook)

```
function pc_grid_horizontal($array, $size) {
    // compute <td> width %ages
    $table_width = 100;
    $width = intval($table_width / $size);
    // define how our <tr> and <td> tags appear
    // sprintf() requires us to use %% to get literal %
    $tr = '<tr align="center">';
    $td = "<td width=\"$width%%\">%s</td>";
    // open table
    $grid = "<table width=\"$table_width%%\">$tr";
    // loop through entries and display in rows of size $sized
    // $i keeps track of when we need a new table tow
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $e) {
        $grid .= sprintf($td, $e);
        $i++;
        // end of a row
        // close it up and open a new one
        if (!($i % $size)) {
            $grid .= "</tr>$tr";
        }
    }
    // pad out remaining cells with blanks
    while ($i % $size) {
        $grid .= sprintf($td, '&nbsp;');
        $i++;
    }
    // add </tr>, if necessary
    $end_tr_len = strlen($tr) * -1;
    if (substr($grid, $end_tr_len) != $tr) {
        $grid .= '</tr>';
    } else {
        $grid = substr($grid, 0, $end_tr_len);
    }
        // close table
        $grid .= '</table>';
        return $grid;
}
```

For example, let’s print the names of the 50 U.S. states in a six-column table:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `states`');
$states = $query->result_array();

// generate the HTML table
$grid = pc_grid_horizontal($states, 6);
print $grid;
```